# Connecting to Spark from R using username password

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

We  have a requirement where in we plan to use sparklyr to execute model code written in R over spark. The spark cluster we use is a kerborised cluster. We are able to connect to this cluster and execute our code using a keytab. The challenge we have now is that we need to use a username password to establish connection instead of using keytab. Any help/pointers on how this could be accomplished would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using RStudio, you can click on `Tools -> Shell` and get a Kerberos ticket using `kinit username@domain`. After that, you can access to a Kerberized cluster using `sparklyr` functions.

Comment: Thanks Jaime for the answer.I believe for me to do a Kinit , I would need to have kerberos installed on my laptop. The RStudio we use is RStudio desktop on widows. We are attempting to connect to a remote spark cluster using  yarn client.

Comment: Another option would be to install RStudio Server on one of the cluster nodes, and execute the `kinit` command from there. We have a similar configuration with a yarn cluster and it works.

Comment: @Jaime - R studio server is currently off the table. I was able to source the kerberos client binaries (MIT Kerberos for Windows 3.2.2) from http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/. I configured leash32 with the krb.conf to point to the remote krb server. I was able to kinit and get the ticket, but it appears the ticket is not getting passed along when I call sparklyr/rhdfs/sparkR. I see a login failed error on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure if that can be done with RStudio Desktop. Maybe asking in the RStudio Support (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us) could confirm you if this is possible.